# Enqueue styles after a plugin

Tags: functions, css, wp-enqueue-style, plugin-cforms

Is there a way to enqueue my `style.css` (and other stylesheets) AFTER a certain plugin enqueues its styles?

Specifically, I want my `style.css` to overwrite cforms's styles, but when I change the priority of the add_action, it doesn't do anything.

Here's what I have:

```
    function rm_theme_styles()  
    {
            wp_register_style( 'rm_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), null, 'all' );
            wp_register_style( 'jquery.fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css', false, null, 'screen' );

            // enqueing:
            wp_enqueue_style( 'rm_styles' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.fancybox' );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rm_theme_styles',10);
```

cforms:

```
    ### some css for positioning the form elements
    function cforms_style() {
        global $wp_query, $cforms_root, $localversion, $cformsSettings;

        ### add content actions and filters
        $page_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

        $exclude  = ($cformsSettings['global']['cforms_inexclude']['ex']=='1');
        $onPages  = str_replace(' ','',stripslashes(htmlspecialchars( $cformsSettings['global']['cforms_inexclude']['ids'] )));
        $onPagesA = explode(',', $onPages);

        if( $onPages=='' || (in_array($page_obj->ID,$onPagesA) && !$exclude) || (!in_array($page_obj->ID,$onPagesA) && $exclude)){

            if( $cformsSettings['global']['cforms_no_css']<>'1' )
                    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $cforms_root . '/styling/' . $cformsSettings['global']['cforms_css'] . '" />'."\n";

                    ### add jQuery script & calendar
                    if( $cformsSettings['global']['cforms_datepicker']=='1' ){
                        wp_enqueue_script('jquery',false,false,false,false);
                        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core',false,false,false,false);
                        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker',false,false,false,false);
                    }
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $cforms_root. '/js/cforms.js"></script>'."\n";

            }
        }
    }

    add_filter('wp_head', 'cforms_style');
```

Comment: Is the code in your question *your* code, or *cforms* code? Can you post both?

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, that's my code. I don't want to mess with cforms's code (or any plugin's code). Cforms is a large plugin and there's no obvious functions.php for it, so I can't post it's code. I just know that it's JS and CSS files are loaded in the header after my enqueued stylesheets.

Comment: "*Cforms is a large plugin and there's no obvious functions.php for it, so I can't post it's code.*" - do a search for `add_action(` to find the Plugin's hook callbacks. You can look specifically for `wp_enqueue_script(` and `wp_enqueue_style(` to find those function calls, or `wp_head` and `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` for possible hook calls.

Comment: @ChipBennett Found it.. Edited above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that cForms is hooking into `wp_head`, and you're attempting to hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. The `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is fired *inside* the `wp_head` hook (at priority `0`, IIRC).

So, your stylesheet is being enqueued at `wp_head`, priority `0`, and the cForms stylesheet is being enqueued at `wp_head`, priority `10`. Since it outputs later, it is taking precedence over yours.

The solution is to use the same `wp_head` hook, with a *lower* priority (i.e. a number *higher* than `10`), for your stylesheet.

Comment: That makes sense, though when I changed the hook and priority, it was either added before cforms again (priority: 1-9) or added to wp_footer() (priority > 9)

`add_action('wp_head', 'rm_theme_styles', 11);`

Comment: Ah, if I echo out the <link>'s (instead of enqueuing them), then they get added to the <head> after cforms using `wp-head` hook and priority 11. It makes more sense just to place the links in header.php. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep; using `wp_head`, you have to echo your stylesheet link. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. :)

Comment: Note also that wp_enqueue_style() allows you to specify other stylesheets as dependencies in it's 3rd parameter:
`$deps An array of registered style handles this stylesheet depends on. Default empty array.`
This wouldn't help in the cforms example as they don't register their stylesheet properly, but in general this is probably the better way to go!

Comment: Great explanation for action hooks. Some plugins even uses other actions, e.g. template_redirect. Thanks!